# Upgrading to SQL Server 2012 from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, upgrade

I need to upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. I am in a new role and have no experience in upgrading.

Before I get started on the upgrade, I wanted to see if there is a check list, tips or tricks, or lesson learned sort of things I can familiarize myself with.

So far I am concerned with following items:

1. Databases
2. Sql Jobs
3. Linked servers
4. Db backup creation
5. Packages
6. Reportserver with 300 reports and subscriptions
7. Cubes
8. User access / roles
9. Application connections / access
10. Individual / overall testings I would need to do

Any suggestions would be helpful.  Let me know if I need to add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The best source to start with is Microsoft. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267(v=sql.110).aspx.  I can tell you this run the upgrade advisor first. As always upgrade in test environment first that way you will have a complete list of things to work on afterwards. Most upgrades go pretty smoothly unless the installer cache has been deleted.